# Can someone help me understand this PHP getting SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql-server

So I am very new to PHP and I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question, but here goes. The code snippet works, but I have no idea what is actually happening, which is making it hard to recreate in other areas with slightly different values. Could anyone shed some light on this for me? Specifically in the two echo statements. Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
<select name="supervisor">
    <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['supervisor']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['supervisor']; ?> 
    </option>
<?php
$sup = mssql_query("USE ERP_VIEW SELECT * FROM quality_users WHERE 
ncr_user = 1 and shop_supervisor = 1") or die();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($sup)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].' " ';
    echo '>'.$row['username'].'</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: There are 4 echo statements. Which are the two you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very basic question but you're basically getting the result of a query to the database and looping through it to form the entries of your dropdown list (`select`).

The object returned by the MySql query is stored into the `$row` variable and for each iteration over the query results you add an `option` entry, which means another item in your dropdown list.

In PHP, in order to display something in the middle of your HTML code you need to `echo` the variable, and that's what you see there. Simply stating the variable won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query starts here `USE ERP_VIEW` you are telling to mysql that your are going to use the `ERP_VIEW` database, then your query says give me all the fields of the table `quality_user` where the fields `ncr_user = 1 and shop_supervisor = 1`.

That's what your query it's going to bring and  `or die()` function means that if mysql can't find the DB or something goes wrong, don't do anything and close the connection.

`while($row = mssql_fetch_array($sup)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].' " ';
    echo '>'.$row['username'].'</option>';
}`

Those lines are going to print the data that you bring from your table into the select options, for example, if in your query's result only gets two people from your table, you are only going to have two options in your select